# Terraform: Use Azure resource group from module in a different module

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure, terraform-modules

I have successfully created a vnet module (with a resource group). But I'm now trying to create an azure public IP address in a compute module, but want to place it in the resource group I created in the vnet module. Please help.

Folder Structure:

```
    c:\terraform
       -main
       -terraform.tfvars
       -variables.tf
    c:\terraform\modules\vnet
       -main
       -output
       -variables
    c:\terraform\modules\compute
      -main
      -variables
      -output
```

contents of c:\terraform\main.tf

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    azurerm = {
      source  = "hashicorp/azurerm"
      version = "=2.68.0"
    }
  }
  backend "azurerm" {
    resource_group_name  = "rg-terraform"
    storage_account_name = "terraform85"
    container_name       = "tfstate"
    key                  = "terraform.tfstate"
  }

}

provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
}


resource "azurerm_resource_group" "compute" {
  name     = "rg-compute"
  location = var.location
}

resource "azurerm_resource_group" "storage" {
  name     = "rg-storage"
  location = var.location
}

#Call vnet child module
module "azure-vnet" {
  source = "./modules/vnet/"

}

#Call compute child module
module "azure-compute" {
  source = "./modules/compute/"

}
```

contents of c:\terraform\variables.tf

```
variable "location" {
  type = string
}
```

contents of c:\terraform\terraform.tfvars

```
location = "UK South"
```

contents of c:\terraform\modules\vnet\main.tf:

```
#This module will create a Azure resource group
#1 virtual network
#3 subnets. 


resource "azurerm_resource_group" "network" {
  name     = "rg-network"
  location = var.location
}

resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "vnet" {
  name                = var.vnet_name
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.network.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.network.name
  address_space       = var.address_space
}

resource "azurerm_subnet" "subnet1" {
  name                 = "AzureBastionSubnet"
  resource_group_name  = azurerm_resource_group.network.name
  virtual_network_name = azurerm_virtual_network.vnet.name
  address_prefixes     = ["172.16.0.0/27"]
}

resource "azurerm_subnet" "subnet2" {
  name                 = "subnet-web"
  resource_group_name  = azurerm_resource_group.network.name
  virtual_network_name = azurerm_virtual_network.vnet.name
  address_prefixes     = ["172.16.0.32/27"]
}

resource "azurerm_subnet" "subnet3" {
  name                 = "subnet-app"
  resource_group_name  = azurerm_resource_group.network.name
  virtual_network_name = azurerm_virtual_network.vnet.name
  address_prefixes     = ["172.16.0.64/27"]
}

resource "azurerm_subnet" "subnet4" {
  name                 = "subnet-core"
  resource_group_name  = azurerm_resource_group.network.name
  virtual_network_name = azurerm_virtual_network.vnet.name
  address_prefixes     = ["172.16.0.96/27"]
}

resource "azurerm_subnet" "subnet5" {
  name                 = "subnet-data"
  resource_group_name  = azurerm_resource_group.network.name
  virtual_network_name = azurerm_virtual_network.vnet.name
  address_prefixes     = ["172.16.0.128/27"]
}
```

contents of C:\terraform\modules\vnet\output.tf

```
output "ResourceGroupid" {
    description = "id of the resource group provisioned"
    value = azurerm_resource_group.network.name
}
```

contents of c:\terraform\modules\vnet\variables.tf:

```
variable "location" {
    type = string
    default = "UK South"
  
}
variable "vnet_name"{
default = "core-vnet"
}

variable "address_space"{
default = ["172.16.0.0/22"]
}
```

contents of c:\terraform\modules\compute\main.tf

```
#This module will create an Azure VM

module "azure-vnet2" {
 source = "../../modules/vnet"
 name = azurerm_resource_group.network.name
 location = "UK South"
  
}

## Create public IP address. Place in the resource group created in the vnet module block - Network resource group.
resource   "azurerm_public_ip"   "myvm1publicip"   { 
   name   =   "pip-vm-dc01" 
   location   =   "UK South" 
   resource_group_name   =   module.azure-vnet2.name
   allocation_method   =   "Dynamic" 
   sku   =   "Basic" 
 }
```

When I run Terraform plan, I get the following error. I know that the compute module is horribly wrong, but I can't figure out what..

```
PS C:\Users\xxxxxxxxx\xxxx> terraform plan

╷
│ Error: Unsupported argument
│
│   on modules\compute\main.tf line 5, in module "azure-vnet2":
│    5:  name = azurerm_resource_group.network.name
│
│ An argument named "name" is not expected here.
```

Comment: Try with `name = module.vnet.ResourceGroupid` instead of `name = azurerm_resource_group.network.name`.

Comment: I tried that but get the below: `│ Error: Unsupported argument
│
│   on modules\compute\main.tf line 5, in module "azure-vnet2":
│    5:  name = module.vnet.ResourceGroupid
│
│ An argument named "name" is not expected here.`

Comment: You haven't showed your `variables`.

Comment: I've included the variables now. I don't have any variables in modules\compute\variables.tf, they are only declared in the root and vnet module. thanks

Comment: @syswiz85 Ah, shouldn't the `name` actually be `vnet_name`? Because the module is expecting a variable with the name `vnet_name`, i.e., shouldn't it be `vnet_name = module.vnet.ResourceGroupid`?

Comment: thanks for the response. In the output file (in vnet module), I only have 1 output and that's the resource group (I think the syntax is correct anyway). In the compute module, I'm trying to deploy a new resource to the resource group (output) from vnet. Are you saying, because I have listed a variable for the vnet name that I also need to call this out in the compute module?

Comment: Well, yes, you can think of modules as functions in other programming languages. If you name a variable that you require as an input with `some_name`, you should pass the variable with the same name to the function, i.e., module in this case. At least that's how it looks to me from what you have added to the question. :)

Comment: Thanks :) will give it a go tomorrow and see how I get on. Thanks for coming back to me, much appreciated. Modules will be the death of me..